# How can I fix the anchor tag for the badge?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my code for the badge:

```
         <Tab
            label={
              <Badge
                badgeContent={size}
                color="secondary"
                showZero
                className={classes.badge}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
              >
                <Typography>Pending</Typography>
              </Badge>
            }
            {...a11yProps(0)}
          />
```

This is the styles for the badge. However, this will also move the typography

```
 badge: {
    marginLeft: "1rem",
  },
```

It can be displayed, however, the anchor tag for the badge is overlapping the words or the label. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Can you include styles in classes.badge ?

Comment: @NeERAJTK I've edited the post

Comment: this will help you checkout [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zvzjqwy0y?fontsize=14&file=/demo.js:495-506)

Comment: Welcome @JenJennie

Comment: @KiranMistry I have another question though, how can I make the badge disappear if the badgeContent is zero?

Comment: you have to remove `showZero` from your code for that you have to add condition for it if you confuse then read [documentation here](https://material-ui.com/components/badges/)

Comment: @KiranMistry Thank you, I just removed the showZero and followed the documentation, it works well now.

Answer (score 1):

```
badge: {
    position: absolute;
    top: '8px';  //you can change according to your use
  },
```

Else

```
anchorOrigin={{
 vertical: "top",
 horizontal: "right",
 position: "absolute",
 top: "8px"
}}
```

Please let me know in a comment if not work